# Jquery function called from $(document).ready takes too long - IE pops up "stop running script" dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I have the following script to mimic "freezepane" functionality in html, like in excel, where the right side and the header are both scrolled when the user scrolls the results table.

```
fnAdjustTable=function(){

    var colCount=$('#firstTr>td').length; //get total number of column

    var m=0;
    var n=0;
    var brow='mozilla';
    jQuery.each(jQuery.browser, function(i, val) {
        if(val==true){

            brow=i.toString();
        }
    });
    $('.tableHeader').each(function(i){
        if(m<colCount){

            if(brow=='mozilla'){
                $('#firstTd').css("width",$('.tableFirstCol').innerWidth());//for adjusting first td

                $(this).css('width',$('#table_div td:eq('+m+')').innerWidth());//for assigning width to table Header div
            }
            else if(brow=='msie'){
                $('#firstTd').css("width",$('.tableFirstCol').width());

                $(this).css('width',$('#table_div td:eq('+m+')').width());//In IE there is difference of 2 px
            }
        }
        m++;
    });

    $('.tableFirstCol').each(function(i){
        if(brow=='mozilla'){
            $(this).css('height',$('#table_div td:eq('+colCount*n+')').outerHeight()-1);//for providing height using scrollable table column height
        }else if(brow=='msie'){

            $(this).css('height',$('#table_div td:eq('+colCount*n+')').innerHeight());
        }else{
            $(this).css('height',$('#table_div td:eq('+colCount*n+')').height());
        }
        n++;
    });



}

fnScroll=function(){

    $('#divHeader').scrollLeft($('#table_div').scrollLeft());
    $('#firstcol').scrollTop($('#table_div').scrollTop());
}
```

The problem is that when iterating through the "tableFirstCol" tds, the error to stop running the script pops up. Is there some more efficient way to do this?

Essentially the script is resizing each top header and side pane to match the width in the first row/column. If I run my report with a large date range (the side header), the script pops up, usually when there are about more than 30 side header rows.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: use IE8's profiler to find out what is taking so long. My guess is that it is the reflows caused by resizing the headers. If that is the case, you need to do the resizing outside of the document; clone the table node and replace it or use the html string.

Comment: @Hemlock, or just use [`detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) then `add()` it back.

Comment: David, when I do a detach at the beginning of the method, and then do I do "add" or "append" to add it back to its own div? I tried these and the resizing/etc does not occur. Trying to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: you have to save a reference to either the parent of the detached or one its nearest sibling then use `add()` or `after()`

Comment: Hmmm the detach/appendTo functions work, but then my table is not a scrollable freeze pane like table anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cache your selectors:

```
var tableDiv = $('#table_div'),
    divHeader = $('#divHeader'),
    firstcol = $('#firstcol'),
    tableFirstCol = $('.tableFirstCol'),
    tds = $('td', tableDiv);
```

You can use for your column selectors .eq(n).

Don't use `$(this).css("height", n)` when `this.style.height = n`; is easier and faster.

This:

```
$('.tableHeader').each(function(i){
    if(m<colCount){
        /* ... */
    }
    m++;
});
```

should be:

```
$('.tableHeader').each(function(i){
    if(i<colCount){
        /* ... */
    }
});
```

and I'm not entirely sure you would even need the `i<colCount` check (but I'd have to see the HTML).

The browser sniffing is probably not necessary. Try applying a reset stylesheet and a valid `doctype` or use [HTML5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com).

If you HAVE to browser sniff: you could just use:

```
if($.browser.mozilla){
    /* ... */
}
else if ($.browser.msie){
    /* ... */
}
else{
    /* ... */
}
```

You could also condense that code down quite a lot. Look up the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Also, as for setting the height of the `tableFirstCol`, couldn't you just set the height of the row instead?

Comment: Thanks, this helped, but the problem is if I do a detach, then the widths all get returned as 0, so nothing is accomplished. If I don't do the detach, the script runs too long.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the HTML with `id` tags for each column and row.  Then just select by the name instead of using the complicated selectors.

I would say that `$('#table_div td:eq('+colCount*n+')')` is a complicated selector, while `$('#row1')` is much easier.

Also - I believe what you are doing for a browser check will not work.  The code you have iterates through all properties for the detected browser and sets the `brow` value to the last one.  Instead of the loop you have, use something like `$.browser.webkit` to check for webkit and `$.browser.msie` to check for IE.  As your code is now, I think you will always be executing the `else` case.  See here for more on the jQuery browser object: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: also note that browser sniffing is bad.  :-)